# Device /dev/spidev* not found

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, dev, flashing, alarm

I have a Banana Pi M1 and wanted to flash libreboot on a ThinkPad T400. I followed [Raspberry Pi (ThinkPad X200)](https://libreboot.org/docs/install/rpi_setup.html), as RPi's GPIO pins are almost the same as BPi's and T400's chip is the same as X200. The only problem is that when it comes to flash the device, **it doesn't appear**

```
$ flashrom -p linux_spi:dev=/dev/spidev0.0,spispeed=512 --chip MX25L6405D -r romread1.rom
flashrom v0.9.9-r1955 on Linux 4.10.9-gnu-1 (armv7l)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at https://flashrom.org

Calibrating delay loop... OK.
linux_spi_init: failed to open /dev/spidev0.0: No such file or directory
Error: Programmer initialization failed.
```

Of course, if the devices /dev/spidev* do not exist!!

```
$ ls /dev/spidev*
ls: cannot access '/dev/spidev*': No such file or directory
$ lsmod|grep spi
spidev                  7364  0
spi_sun4i               4955  0
```

I've tried everything: loading spidev, spi-gpio, spi_sun4i kernels modules, different pinouts, etc. Maybe I've not got the right pinout? /dev/spidev* devices show up if there's nothing connected to the GPIO pins? **how can I test them with sth. easier?**

In almost all of the problems, people solve it by editing /boot/config.txt but that's only for RPi afaik. Anyways, the kernel I've installed in it does not have that file.

---

SoC: Allwinner A20
RAM: 1GB
OS: [image] [Parabola GNU/Linux-libre](https://www.parabola.nu/) (Arch Linux and ALARM based, without proprietary software packages)
BPi's GPIO pins: https://bananapi.gitbooks.io/bpi-m1/content/en/Banana-Pi-GIPO.png
More specs: https://bananapi.gitbooks.io/bpi-m1/en/

---

**EDIT:** There are some devices in /dev which *look* like sth. near to /dev/spidev* devices:

```
/dev/gpiochip0
/dev/gpiochip1
/dev/hidraw0
/dev/hidraw1
/dev/iio:device0
/dev/iio:device1
```

I say "near" because flashrom says:

```
# flashrom -p linux_spi:dev=/dev/gpiochip0
flashrom v0.9.9-r1955 on Linux 4.13.5-gnu-1 (armv7l)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at https://flashrom.org

Calibrating delay loop... OK.
linux_spi_init: failed to set SPI mode to 0x00: Invalid argument
Error: Programmer initialization failed.
```

For all those devices it says `Invalid argument` with whatever I put in "spispeed" (better than `Inappropriate ioctl for device`). I suspect that `/dev/gpiochip0` *might* be the chip? However, if it is, IDK how to solve the problem of "Invalid argument"

Comment: Have you figured it out by any  chance?

Comment: no way, I gave up a long time ago, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Type `vi /boot/config.txt`
- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter ‘insert’ mode.
- Delete the `#` in front of `dtparam=spi=on` to un-comment the line
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>:wq</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

Comment: "In almost all of the problems, people solve it by editing /boot/config.txt but that's only for RPi afaik. Anyways, **the OS I installed in it does not have that file**." - I should have say "the kernel I installed in it does not have that file", but you understand that, so read more carefully next time